# How to call all instances of a class from another class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, instance

I have two classes

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, position):  
        self.position = position


class Bike:

    def __init__(self, position):          
        self.position = position
```

In a separate file I am creating multiple cars and bikes:

```
cars_list = [Car(position[i]) for i in range(position_list)]
```

I would like to call and use `cars_list` in the `Bike` class every time I create a `Bike` instance at that current moment.

```
class Bike:

    def __init__(self, position):          
        self.position = position
        for i in cars_list:
            # continue with code
```

So if `cars_list` happen to change before a new `Bike` is created then the current `cars_list` is called in `Bike`. The way I know how to do this is to add another argument to `Bike` where

```
def __init__(self, position, cars_list):          
            self.position = position
            for i in cars_list:
                # continue with code
```

and when calling bike, `cars_list` is passed as an argument. However is there a way to store the current `cars_list` in the Class `Car` and then create a method in that class called `get_current_instances` so it can be called in the `Bike` class?

Comment: You could simply do `Car.cars_list = [...]`, and then access that from anywhere you have access to the `Car` class. But that sounds really really insane and I cannot imagine what you're trying to do with that. At the very least, you should pass the list as argument to `Bike`, as you're doing.

Comment: @deceze Strictly speaking a global list will do the job, but since the OP is going to the trouble of defining classes, it makes sense to avoid globals. Class attributes and class methods are entirely the right use case to use, if the OP wants to do a OOP solution.

Comment: @Tony Using class attributes is not doing "OOP"…

Comment: @deceze I beg to differ. Even C++ offers static attributes which is the same as a class attribute. It might not be pure OOP, but it is a common idiom in many languages. It is certainly better than a global.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Class attributes are just global state in a namespace.

Comment: I don't disagree technically - but they are better than a straight program wide global - although Python doesn't support them either.
In 'pure' OOP - how do you support class wide data - i.e. data that needs to affects every instance in that class simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic use case for class attributes, and a class method on Car - literally you want to store and retrieve data about the Car class.

For example:

```
class Car:
    car_list = []

    def __init__(self, position):  
        self.position = position
        Car.car_list.append(self)

   @classmethod
   def get_current_instances(cls):
       return Car.car_list


class Bike:
    def __init__(self, position):          
        self.position = position

   # Example method to show how the Car class is used
   def move(self, position):
       cars = Car.get_current_instances()
       for car in cars:
           if car.position == position:
              self.crash() # Arrgh a crash between the bike and car
           else:
               self.position = position
```

Comment: I am getting an error when entering @classmethod: NameError: name 'car_list' is not defined. I think you meant to write 'cls.car_list' and in __init__ 'Car.car_list.append(self)'